# Custom jupyter kernel in a continuous restart loop

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-kernel

I have a custom jupyter kernel written. The kernel as such seems to work OK because I can test it by starting it from the command line like so `python3 -m kernelname` and eventually execute commands.

But the notebook just doesn’t connect. It appears to enter an infinite loop of `connecting to the kernel` due to a websocket connection failure.

Attached is the error on the console.

Few forums recommended to downgrade tornado to 5.1.1. Currently it is at this version, but the issue persists. Can someone help me fix it please?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: This was cross-posted [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/custom-jupyter-kernel-in-a-continuous-restart-loop/20481?u=fomightez). Those stumbling upon this issue may want to check there as well.

Comment: Any recommendations on how do I resolve this?